# reset sequence number in quickfix

Tags: c++, quickfix

I am working with a broker that tells me not to reset the sequence numbers on logon, except at the beginning of the week.
However, if the sequence numbers get out of wack, I am supposed to use tag 141 in the logon message to request a sequence number reset. Obviously I can check the rejected logons for being rejected for sequence number too low, and set the tag in the onlogon, but how do I tell quickfix that it needs to reset it's sequence numbers? this is a difficult feature to test since connection issues that fowl the sequence numbers dont happen very often.

Im using the C++ version of quickfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can monitor for the proper message in the `LOGOUT` message. If it's something like "msgseqnum too low" set a flag to reset on the next `LOGON` message. This is from the `FIX::Application::fromAdmin` implementation.

Then in your `FIX::Application::toAdmin` implementation check if the message is a `LOGON` and there's a reset flag set. If so, lookup your session (`FIX::Session::lookupSession`) and call `setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(1)` and `setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(1)`. Also reset your flag :)